# JQuery add elements with bootstrap styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a button to a specific HTML element using jQuery similar to,  (https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp)

My issue is that when I try and run the code,

```
var txt1 = "<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary">text</button>";        
$("#thing1").append(txt1);     // Append new elements
```

I don't get the styling I am wanting and it is messing up another part of my code unless I do the same as above, except without the bootstrap styling like,

```
    var txt1 = "<button">text</button>";        
    $("#thing1").append(txt1);     // Append new elements
```

It works fine with the second example except for that the button styling doesn't use bootstrap like I am wanting in the first example and am not sure as to why?

A more complete picture of the code is below,

```
    <script>
function askName(){
    var name = prompt("What's your name?");
    var message = "Hello " + name + ", would you like to build a table?"
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = message;



    var txt1 = "<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary">text</button>";        
    $("#thing1").append(txt1);     // Append new elements

};

function tables(){
 var txt1 = "<p>Text.</p>";              // Create text with HTML
    var txt2 = $("<p></p>").text("Text.");  // Create text with jQuery
    var txt3 = document.createElement("p");
    txt3.innerHTML = "Text.";               // Create text with DOM
    $("body").append(txt1, txt2, txt3);     // Append new elements

}


</script>


<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({
            left: '250px',
            opacity: '0.5',
            height: '150px',
            width: '150px'
        });
    });
});
</script> 

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

<button type = "button" class= "btn btn-primary" onclick="askName()">
    Want to chat?
</button>
</div>

<h3 style = "text-align: center"class="text-primary" id="output"></h3>

<div id = thing1>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have a problem where you should be mixing your " and your '

try this:

```
var txt1 = "<button type = 'button' class = 'btn btn-primary'>text</button>";
```

Comment: You are completely right! I didn't realize that, Thanks a ton! One other issue though is that the button is being placed on the page, but is defaulting to its disabled (greyed out) coloring? Do you happen to see what might be causing that?

Comment: nope nothing stands out. When you inspect it does the button have a "disabled" attribute? I think it shouldn't.. maybe its just some css somewhere?

Comment: Ya, that was my first thought was looking at inline and external styling but nothing is showing up as a clear reason. I'll figure it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is with your quotes

```
var txt1 = "<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary">text</button>";        
$("#thing1").append(txt1);     // Append new elements
```

try

```
var txt1 = '<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary">text</button>';        
$("#thing1").append(txt1);     // Append new elements
```